# Backbone: How To Bind A Model To A View

Tags: javascript, data-binding, backbone.js

So I have some objects extended from Backbone.js:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var modelInstance = new MyModel();
var MyModelView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to bind my Model to its corresponding View. How does one handle data-binding in Backbone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass your model instance into the view when creating it.

```
var modelView = new MyModelView({model: modelInstance})
```

From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

```
When creating a new View, the options you pass — after being merged into any default 
options already present on the view — are attached to the view as this.options 
for future reference. There are several special options that, if passed, will be 
attached directly to the view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes.
```